# Why is this code failing?

Tags: python, git

```
class Chdir:
    """ change in and out of dir """
    def __init__(self, newPath):
        self.newPath = newPath

    def __enter__(self):
        self.savedPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.newPath)

    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.savedPath)
```

using above,

```
    ROOT = "/home/username/my-blog/blogname/"
    with Chdir(ROOT):
        print os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+'/.git')
        print os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+'/notes/')
        subprocess.Popen(['git', 'add', '--ignore-removal', 'notes/'])
```

The output:

```
True
True
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

From the print statement tests, it is clear that a `git repository exists`and a subsequent notes folder also exists. But still the code is failing

**EDIT**
Shell script to test

```
  1 echo "Testing ...."
  2 cd /home/username/my-blog/blogname/
  3 git add --ignore-removal notes/
  4 git add --ignore-removal data.json
  5 git status
```

on `source test.sh` I am getting the usual blurb

```
Testing ....
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
.... etc
```

Full source

```
class Git:

    def __init__(self, message="GitNote Commit"):
        self.message = message


    def __enter__(self):
        with Chdir(ROOT):
            print os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+'/.git')
            print os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+'/notes/')
            subprocess.Popen(['git', 'add', '--ignore-removal', 'notes/'], cwd=ROOT)
            subprocess.Popen(['git', 'add', '--ignore-removal', 'data.json'], cwd=ROOT)
            subprocess.Popen(['git', 'add', '--ignore-removal', 'images/'], cwd=ROOT)
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        with Chdir(ROOT):
            changed_files = subprocess.check_output(['git','diff',
                            '--name-only','HEAD']).split('\n')[:-1]
            relevant_changes = [f for f in changed_files if f[-3:]=='.md'
                                and os.path.isfile(ROOT+f)]
        for item in relevant_changes:
                yield item

    def __exit__(self,exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_type is not None:
            print exc_type, exc_value, traceback
        subprocess.Popen(['git', '--no-pager', 'commit', '-m', self.message])
```

Comment: Have you tried running `git add --ignore-removal notes/` from the command-line? Also, you wrote `with Cd` but your class is called `Chdir`.

Comment: @Mark yes, it works without issue. Fixed the typo

Comment: Did you run the command in the "/home/username/my-blog/blogname/" directory?

Comment: I've had problems with invoking processes from PHP where it doesn't actually respect the current working directory. I suspect that's what's happening here. I'd try using the full path in place of "notes/"

Comment: @Parker yes, I did. I have included a test shell script at the end

Comment: Might be worthwhile to state that `subprocess.check_output` in `__iter__` does not raise any errors for some reason and works fine independently.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [`cwd` kwarg of `Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) instead.

e.g.,

```
subprocess.Popen(['git', 'add', '--ignore-removal', 'notes/'], cwd=ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I have now included my full class in the question.

Comment: @pad Your problem must be elsewhere then. I tried this in my command-line and the `cwd` arg works as expected. `os.chdir` works as expected too for that matter.